# How to check if libfftw3_threads.so.3.2.4 shared library was compiled for pthreads or for OpenMP?

Tags: linux, libraries

There is FFTW library installed by an administrator system-wide, in `/usr/lib64`, and it includes `/usr/lib64/libfftw3_threads.so.3.2.4`.

When I compiled this library myself, before it was installed by sysadmin, I have noticed that you have to choose between **OpenMP** and **pthreads** version:

> - `--enable-openmp`: Like `--enable-threads`, but using OpenMP compiler directives in order to induce parallelism rather than spawning its own threads directly. Useful especially for programs already employing such directives, in order to minimize conflicts between different parallelization mechanisms. Use either `--enable-openmp` or `--enable-threads`, not both; in either case the multi-threaded FFTW interface/library (see Multi-threaded FFTW) is compiled (with different back ends).

The distribution is Gentoo, so theoretically either is possible.

How to check if said library was compiled with OpenMP support (which would be best), or with pthreads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check whether the library is linked against pthread at least by using `ldd`. On Debian squeeze, my version is linked against pthread.

```
$ ii  libfftw3-3      3.2.2-1      library for computing Fast Fourier Transforms

$ ldd /usr/lib/libfftw3_threads.so.3.2.4
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb77be000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i686/cmov/libm.so.6 (0xb776c000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xb7753000)   <---
libc.so.6 => /lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb760c000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb77bf000)
```

Based on a quick net search, it looks like the program would have to link against the [GCC OpenMP support library (GOMP)](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/gomp/) for OpenMP support, so you could use `ldd` to check for something with "libgomp" in it as well.

Answer (score 5):

You can call `ldd` on it to see if `-fopenmp` was used:

```
$ cat x.c 
int foo()
{ return 0 ; }

$ gcc -shared -fopenmp x.c -o x.so
$  ldd x.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff293d6000)
    libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007fa942998000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa94277b000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa9423f7000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007fa9421ef000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa942dc7000)
```

Meaning it is both linked against libpthread and libgomp.

```
$ gcc -shared x.c -o x.so
$ ldd x.so                        
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff5fbff000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5340a9b000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f534103f000)
```

Meaning it does not include openmp support.

In general it is not that easy to see what compiler flags were used [since they are not recorded in the binary by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189350/detect-gcc-compile-time-flags-of-a-binary).

Perhaps you can look into some Gentoo log file that was created during package install (I mean package compile time).

Of course with binary package based distribution (like e.g. Debian) you don't have that problem - you can look up to what package the .so file belongs to, and look into the package description and/or the source package, where the  compiler switches are specified.